# angles in mud flat cracks

Tags: material-science

This image of a cracked mud flat from
https://www.msichicago.org/explore/whats-here/exhibits/numbers-in-nature/the-patterns/voronoi-pattern/
shows that when three cracks meet at a vertex they (tend to) form right angles.

[image]

I remember once reading about why that happens - I think it was an energy minimizing argument of some sort. I'd like to see that argument again - and a link to a quotable source, if possible.

(Reason for my curiosity: if my memory is correct then this cannot be a Voronoi diagram, as claimed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Physics Today](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/PT.3.2584) had an article on the subject a few years ago (not sure if that link is paywalled or not - I'm a member).  Maybe that's what you were thinking of?  The  article explains it in terms of local elastic energy balancing.

Comment: That's not where I read it, but it does answer my question and it's not paywalled. Thanks.

Comment: In general posts linking to articles as answers are discouraged (as if the link goes dead so does the answer).  You should ideally write a summary of the key relevant points of the article, not just link to it.